# Taking a rolling average of three records at a time with two group by values

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, average

The data I am working with has no primary key, instead it is grouped by a TMC value and a date value. What I am trying to do is take 5 minute epoch values and combine them into a 15 minute epoch by average three records at a time. So epoch 0, 1, 2 are averaged together to get a new record, then 3,4,5 and so on. Here is a sample table. I don't know how to format this correctly:

```
TMC         DATE    EPOCH   TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES
113N04415   1012016 0       228
113N04415   1012016 1       228
113N04415   1012016 2       222
113N04415   1012016 3       224
113N04415   1012016 4       229
113N04415   1012016 5       223
```

I think I am close with this code, as it works for the first record but fails for the second:

```
select tmc, date, avg(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) AS TRAVEL_avg
from (select I40_2016_ALL.*, 
             row_number() over (order by TMC, date, epoch) as rn 
      from I40_2016_ALL) I40_2016_ALL
where tmc = '113n04415' and date = '1012016'
group by TMC, DATE, floor((rn - 1) / 3)
ORDER BY TMC, DATE
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you are actually using. MySQL doesn't as yet implement a window function like `row_number` afaik.

Comment: RDBMS? I am using microsoft sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer division like this:

```
SELECT TMC, [DATE], EPOCH, AVG(TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) AS TRAVEL_avg       
FROM (
   SELECT TMC, [DATE], TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TMC, [DATE], EPOCH) AS rn
   FROM I40_2016_ALL) AS t
GROUP BY TMC, [DATE], (rn -1)/ 3
ORDER BY TMC, [DATE]
```

This query places rows `1,2,3` in one group, rows `4, 5, 6` in the next group, etc.

Comment: That didn't do anything, just shows the vanilla records.

Comment: @BenZeddicus Apologies. I inadvertently included `EPOCH` field in the `GROUP BY` clause. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: That works but the ordering is all over the place. I need it to be in order by tmc and date.

Comment: @BenZeddicus Then add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
SELECT AVG(TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) 
FROM
(
SELECT TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES AS TRAVEL_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES
,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by EPOCH) + 2)/3 AS GroupID
FROM
YourTable
) AS d
GROUP BY d.GroupID
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'RANK'.
Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Sorry I removed the RANK, replaced with EPOCH

Comment: Still has a error with windowed functions can only appear in the select or order by clauses.

Comment: are you sure? I have taken it off the inner select

Comment: Msg 2809, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The request for procedure 'I40_2016_ALL' failed because 'I40_2016_ALL' is a table object.

Answer (score 0):

Ummmm, didn't try this but what about:

```
    select tmc, date, floor((epoch + 1) / 3) as part, 
           avg(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) AS TRAVEL_avg
      from I40_2016_ALL
     where tmc = '113n04415' and date = '1012016'
     group by TMC, DATE, floor((epoch + 1) / 3)
```

Or if you want every line with the total...

```
        select tmc, date, floor((epoch + 1) / 3) as part, 
               avg(Travel_TIME_ALL_VEHICLES) 
                over (partition by TMC, DATE, floor((epoch + 1) / 3)) AS TRAVEL_avg
          from I40_2016_ALL
         where tmc = '113n04415' and date = '1012016'
```

Comment: There is no FROM clause in these.

Comment: Much better but the segmenting is off by one. The first two records are by themselves and the last record is by itself. Which I would assume is due to there being 287 total records. So somewhere is there going to be just 2 records being averaged.

Comment: I corrected your code by removing the +1 from the epochs, which has discovered another issue. The epoch values are not consistent, as there are gaps in the numbering. This is seen at part 21, where the epoch 64 is missing. Is there a means to correct for this?

Comment: Ya, you are right, the "+1" had to go... Let me understand, you want to group them by groups of 3 physical records or by groups of 3 consecutive "epoch" ? So (0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(9,11),(12,13,14) together even if 10 is missing ? Or (0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(9,11,12),(13,14) which would be by physical row number ?

Comment: Yes, we have gotten to the point where the ordering works as long as the epochs are not missing records. Which they are. So some segments are averaging on a 5 minute or 10 minute period, which doesn't work. So this ordering should be what I am trying to aim for:

Comment: (1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)(11,12,13) So even though 10 is missing the code just skips over it and averages the next three.

Comment: Well then use @Giorgos Betsos solution that uses the "row_number()" function.

Comment: I think the solution to this is to add a column to the table that has a new ordering that doesn't have skips in it, then run the code off of that. So far I've been unable to figure out how to update the table correctly.

Comment: WITH myUpdate (myRowNumber)
AS (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY TMC, DATE ORDER BY TMC, DATE, EPOCH) - 1) AS myRowNumber
FROM [dbo].[I40_2016_ALL])
 --SELECT * FROM myUpdate
update  [dbo].[I40_2016_ALL]
set MOD_EPOCH = myRowNumber
FROM MYUPDATE